# How to customize the standart hibernate validation using inheritance?

Tags: java, spring, validation, customization, hibernate-validator

I annotate field like this:

```
@Min(100)
private Long cost;
```

To achieve dynamic update of min value I extended from hibernate validator class:

```
public class CustomMinValidator extends MinValidatorForNumber {
    public void initialize(final Long minValue) {
        Min min = new Min() {
            @Override
            public String message() {
                return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?>[] groups() {
                return new Class<?>[0];
            }

            @Override
            public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long value() {
                return minValue;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                return null;
            }
        };
        super.initialize(min);
    }
}
```

Register bean, which will refresh min value from config:

```
@Component
public class MinValidatorRefresher {
    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;
    @Autowired
    CustomMinValidator customMinValidator;

    @PostConstruct
    private void refreshMinValue() {
        Long minValue;
        try {
            minValue = Long.valueOf(messageSource.getMessage("Terminal.MinValue", null, Locale.getDefault()));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return;
        }
        customMinValidator.initialize(minValue);
    }
}
```

when I start my application I see the following message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.terminal.domain.validation.validators.CustomMinValidator com.terminal.configuration.MinValidatorRefresher.customMinValidator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.terminal.domain.validation.validators.CustomMinValidator] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:290)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.terminal.domain.validation.validators.CustomMinValidator] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481)
    ... 67 more
```

Message is clear for me but I don't understand how to fix it?

### P.S.

My main idea that I want to extend class which uses hibernate by default and replace it with my new implementation.

Comment: It seems you can get this to work, but I am wondering whether this a good idea. Since you are still using the @Min annotation in the entity itself, you will have to set some value there (since it is required). At the same time you potentially use a different value via your external configuration file. I find this confusing and potentially very misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@Component` tag to `CustomMinValidator` class.

```
@Component
public class CustomMinValidator extends MinValidatorForNumber
```

and also to initiate a bean, you need `no-arg` constructor inside `CustomMinValidator` class. Since, you don't have any other constructors, the default no-arg constructor should be sufficient.